# Reporting Services Client side

Tags: reporting, service, client-side

I need to compose a report using multiple subreports, "chained" together at runtime in a C# Forms project.

The subreports each represent a subtest of a product, and the data needs special formatting to make sense to the report users ( Special graphs, sensible column names with/without engineering details etc )

I Imagine that every Subreport has a subreport field so that I at runtime can insert the next subreport into. Obviously the first (main) report has a subreport as well, and a finalizing subreport does not (summary subreport)

Is it possible to build chain subreports together at runtime ?

Does anyone out there have a sample?

Kind Regards
Jes

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is possible with the Reporting Services product, but I don't know how to do it. In our experience as part of the ActiveReports team, we've found that subreports are also not always the most performant and memory efficient way to accomplish this.

For information about how we suggest to do this with our ActiveReports product see the following explanation:
http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arHOWInsertOrAddPages.html

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity - Data Dynamics
```